# What's the difference between 気を使う and 気にする?

Tags: nuances

What's the difference between 気を使う and 気にする?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～に気を使う (also written as 気を遣う) has a positive connotation. It means actively paying attention to something/someone that actually matters. On the other hand, ～を気にする is neutral, but can have a negative/passive connotation depending on the context. It may mean you worry about something even though you don't need to.

- ～に気を使う: to care; to be mindful; to pay attention; to be attentive
- ～を気にする: to worry; to be concerned; to be bothered

Note that you can both say {髪型/彼}を気にする and {髪型/彼}に気を使う.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer at https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/6361349

気にする
自分が思う。ex. 髪形を気にする

気を使う
相手に対して。ex.彼に気を使う